# Mocking a network connection

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

Just how about do I mock a network connection?

Suppose I am writing a client-server topology; the client is already in place, but I want to test that when a network connection is received on the server that an event is fired; or that a function is called in response to a network connection being received.

I'm currently using EventMachine, and I'd like to figure out how to unit test these interactions to make sure that mocked network connections/messages will be handled correctly **without** having to do integration testing and actually having to write a clien tthat would send the appropriate messages to the test interface. I hope this makes sense?

Basically, I want to be able to have a test for the Server to make sure it responds to mocked messages correctly without having to ever open a real internet connection or write a dedicated client just for testing - I would prefer to be able to be able to say 'This is the message I want to receive, now pretend i've received it from a real client and handle it'

Comment: I must say that I don't know much about Ruby but surely there's a semi-acceptable mocking framework that could be used to tackle this?

Comment: It's not a question of using a mocking framework, I'm asking how to mock the interaction between a connection connecting to the server and it's interaction. :( For example, I want to find out how I can 'make' my class realize it has received a connection. EventMachine seems to do it by magic

Comment: A better example would be in C# (although it still happens in Ruby too) where you have the BeginAcceptAsync method - how do you fire an event in a test to say that a connection has been received (and thereby call EndAcceptAsync)?

Comment: I think I just answered my own question... Use a mocking framework to mock the Begin/EndAcceptConnection methods (or their correspondants in Ruby) and make the Begin method immediately call the End method

Comment: it depends (at least a bit) on the code your testing...could you add an example of the code/method in question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this simply by instantiating an instance of the connection class in EventMachine and tehn calling the method directly - not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place!

```
describe 'Network manager' do
  it 'should call the ChangeStatus handler when it receives the ChangeStatus packet' do
    # Arrange
    connection = TcpConnection.new
    # Set up the packet handler
    packet_handler = double 'TcpPacketHandler'
    # Inject dependency
    connection.packet_handler = packet_handler
    # Create the message

    data = [ 15, # message code + payload size
      0, # message code
      4, # protocol version
      12, # size of string
    ]

    data.push 'hello, world'.bytes.to_a
    reader, writer = IO.pipe
    writer.write data
    writer.close


    puts data

    # Assert
    expect(packet_handler).to receive(:handle_message).with(data[1], anything()).once

    message = reader.read
    # Act
    connection.receive_data message
  end
end
```